# In laravel, get an errror when show the product items

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get some view data using laravel. here is my code:

```
public function brandsview($cate_url, $brand_url)
{        
    $brands = Brands::where('url',$brand_url)->first();
    $brand_id = $brands->id;
    $products = Products::where('brand_id',$brand_id)
        ->where('status','!=','Hide')
        ->where('status','Show')
        ->get();
   
    return view('lokalproductspage.brands')
        ->with('brands', $brands)
        ->with('products', $products);
}
```

I get the error `trying to get property 'id' of non-object`. Please help me.

Comment: I'm guessing it didn't find a matching brand, so `$brands` is null instead of an object.

Comment: any suggestions to fix it? im just really new to this

Comment: You can use `firstOrFail` instead of `first`, which will throw an error if the brand isn't found. If you think it should exist, try `Log::info($brand_url);` and look in your logs to make sure that it contains what you think it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: try putting return $brands instead of return view and see if that returns anything.

Comment: please use dd($brands->id) before accessing it and check if is not null. I'm sure this is null and also check $brand_url if it has spaces before or after or is it ok?

Comment: i follow your instruction sir nomah but it is still the same error. it is not null i also check if there spaces but still error :((

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $brands return nothing, are you checked it?
If return of $brands is not stable may be u should add some checks before use attributes like 'id'

Comment: i checked it multiple times but it still display that error

Answer (score 0):

Change **first()** to **firstOrFail()**, which will let you know if you actually found a record. Normally your error suggests there was no record found. It is a nice way to show a 404 if the user put a bad url in.

```
$brands = Brands::where('url',$brand_url)->firstOrFail();
```